# KafkaMessageListenerContainer vs ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, messaging

If I use listener.concurrency property, would this use KafkaMessageListenerContainer or ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer?
Note I have not defined any beans explicitly and I leave the required bean creation to spring boot.

I wanted to know if my understanding is correct. I would want parallelism in consuming the message from topic which has got multiple partitions say 3. So is it fine if I configure it in `application.yml` file as follows. I have tried below configuration and see 3 consumers were created.

```
spring:
   kafka:
     consumer:
        group-id: group-id
        key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
     producer:
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
     listener:
        concurrency: 3
```

So my question is, do I have to create a bean to configure `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` or the above listener configuration would internally would use `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` instead of `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` when it sees `listener.concurrency=3`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency= # Number of threads to run in the listener containers.
```

`Concurrency` is the property of `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.` If we are defining this property in `application.yml` means we want to use `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.`

[image]

In Kafka, only one consumer is allowed to read data from one partition at a time. 
Using `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` will provide only single threaded message listener consumer. [KafkaMessageListenerContainer](http://KafkaMessageListenerContainer)

Using `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` will provide the number of `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` defined in the `Concurrency` property in `application.yml`.

We can get the same behavior using following  `Listener using Java code.`

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaListenerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "1111");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        return props;
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to go through the below link to have a practical example of the same.

https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/25/spring-kafka-multi-threaded-message-consumption/

Comment: Does that mean -> if "concurrency: 3" is set, one consumer (pod) will pull 3 messages at a time and process it parallelly?  I Am a bit confused, can you help?

Comment: think of the concurrent consumers of a consumer group as totally  independent consumers each consuming data from a partition. If there are 3 partitions of the topic and 3 concurrent consumers, each concurrent consumer would be able to process data parallely.  More explanation here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727660/spring-kafka-messagelistenercontainer